# Running Chrome using Selenium stalls after about 100 execute_script calls

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium

I am running into problems running Chrome using Selenium combined with Python.

Starting the browser and loading the right URL works fine. 
However, when I use the execute_script method to call a simple JS function once every second, the script hangs after about 100 calls. 
No errors are being logged. The only thing the JS function does, is move the focus to another element.

The same thing works fine when I'm running Firefox the same way.

I am using the following software:

- Ubuntu 12.04
- Selenium 2.33.0
- ChromeDriver server for linux32 (v2.0.203537.dyu) with support for Chrome v27-29
- Chrome 27
- Python 2.7.3

Any help would be very much appreciated.

This is my simple test script:

```
import os
import sys
import time

import base.configLinux as config
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

calls = 0

options = Options()
options.add_argument("--disable-web-security") 
options.add_argument("--disable-gpu") 
options.add_argument("--start-maximized")

browser = webdriver.chrome.webdriver.WebDriver(executable_path=config.webDriverPath, port=0, chrome_options=options, service_args=None, desired_capabilities=None, service_log_path=None)
browser.get(config.url) 

def sendTrigger():

    global calls

    browser.execute_script("trigger(39)") 
    calls = calls + 1

    sys.stdout.write(" calls: " + str(calls) + os.linesep)

while True:
    sendTrigger()
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: What is it actually hanging on?  Have you tried stepping in to `browser.execute_script` starting around call 100?  Have you looked at what's going on in the browser using developer tools or anything?

Comment: I did check the browser developer tools, but I did not find anything which could contribute - as far as I know - to the problem.

Comment: Could you be more specific than "a while"?  If you can change the title to reflect the actual behavior of the software ("runs slowly", "cannot process script", etc) that might make your question more interesting to other members.

Comment: I found the solution: set service_log_path to /dev/null .